# Using a for loop to check id JSON key exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, ejs

I am trying to iterate through EJS JSON object and check if the values exist and then if they do, push the url further down to an array.

When I load the page, I am being told, count is undefined. What is the issue and how do I fix this?

```
var urlArray = [];
        var product = '<%= product %>';
        console.log(product);
        var count;
        for (count = 1; count < 6 count++) {
            if (product.data["product.thumbgallery" + count] === undefined) {
                urlArray.push( <%- product.data['product.imageGallery' + count].value.main.url %>)
                }
            }
```

Edit: Count was a mistake. I changed the variable name after I encountered the error;

Comment: To check for `undefined` you should use the [typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to prohibit throwing an `Uncaught ReferenceError`

Comment: `count < 6 i++` should be `count < 6; i++`

Comment: Count was a mistake. I changed the variable name after I encountered the error.

Comment: OK, so if you have fixed that, what is the question? You would need to call `JSON.parse(product)`, *or* remove the quotes from around `<%= product %>`. Why is there a `<%- %>` wrapper around what you have in `.push()`?

Comment: count is still undefined in all of the scopes below the if statment

Comment: Do you mean the one inside the `<%- %>`? Or in later code that you don't show?

Comment: In the lines with if and push

Comment: OK, one more time: why is the `<%- %>` wrapper in that `.push()` line?

Comment: I'm using EJS as the templating engine for node. http://ejs.co/ Node is passing then object in through the EJS view engine.

Comment: Yes. So isn't that running server-side? Can the code inside `<% %>` reference client code variables that are outside? I wouldn't think so. What happens if you remove the `<%- %>` and just say `urlArray.push( product.data['product.imageGallery' + count].value.main.url)`? (Other than the fact that it doesn't make sense because the if condition has just determined that that is `undefined`...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterator variable is count but you are iterating i in your for loop. Shouldn't it be count++ if I am not mistaken.

```
for (count = 1; count < 6; count++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I t should be

```
For (int count; ....then the rest)
```

you declared the initial variable to start your continuation argument outside of the loop. This simple mistake can cause the compiler to not recognize the declaration of the variable as legitimate when executing the continuation of the loop.

It may not be the source of this particular error, but debugging has to start somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Int is a data type used in lower level languages like Java or C++. Int represents a whole number with no decimal whereas in javascript var encompasses any number plus strings, objects, arrays etc. Javascript is interpreted on the fly by the web browser and not compiled like lower level languages. Lower level meaning it's closer down the tree to binary.

Comment: @Quesofat you can use whatever data type you want. I program in java, JS, C#, and Python. In all of them you need the full variable declaration inside of the for loop for your continuation argument to be valid on each pass. No matter the declared type the variable must be explicitly declared  within the for loop to complete the updating and then comparison to execute.

Comment: `All three expressions in the head of the for loop are optional.

For example, in the initialization block it is not required to initialize variables:`

Comment: All of them are either inside the for loop or fully declared outside the loop. You have a partially declared variable with no value then you assign a 1 at the same time you try to use it. The link you sent explains the same concept. Assign the value  on the same line then use it inside the loop or fully declare the variable inside the loop. It's most definitely required to fully declare a variable either before or within your for loop. I don't want to argue over something so simple. Sorry you didn't find my feedback helpful. Good luck.

Comment: The issue was I was missing a semi-colon. Between count > 6 and count++ compounded by the fact that I forgot assigned the ejs variable already and was trying to call it wish ejs wrappers. The scopes here were appropriate for js.

Comment: Glad you found the bug. Guess I shouldn't look at code this late. Mark it as answered?

Comment: Sounds like neither of us should. Unfortunately I don't have a correct answer to mark.